# How can I prevent the Meetup.com e-mails from cluttering my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

How can I prevent the Meetup.com e-mails from cluttering my Google Calendar? It has to be, because of the confirmation e-mail that Meetup.com sends and Google Calendar automatically adds them to my calendar.

There is an unsubscribe link in the e-mails, but unfortunately I am a member of 100+ meet-up groups and you have to change all settings manually per group. It's not even that obvious which of the 20 checkbox-settings per group has to be unchecked to disable the "See you at"-emails.

Is there a way I can make sure that Meet-up e-mails, especially the ones titled "See you at..." no longer create items in my Google Calendar?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this problem? What did customer service say?